# Aligning div's with different titles

Tags: css, html, alignment

My task is to align div's, which contain another div, where I put a title. The problem is that when the number of lines needed for the title is different, they are not aligned properly. Here is an [example on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aHBXN/), which could explain the problem better. I want the `div`'s to be aligned next to each other like the div's with single-lined titles.

Comment: Try using % instead of px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vertical-align:top;`

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/aHBXN/1/